# How to disable the double tap to zoom in Wkwebkit iOS 11?

Tags: html, ios11

I need to disable double tap to zoom in my iOS Webkit, which is loaded from local html file.

Answer (score 0):

It cant be done with pure html, but with JavaScript, as of IOS 10 at least, you should be able to use the following, I have tested it on IOS 10, but not IOS 11, so let me know if it fails.

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (event) {
  if (event.scale !== 1) { event.preventDefault(); }
}, { passive: false });
```

Comment: where should i add it, if i cant add it as pure html ? i am using xcode 10.